# Add arrows to ListLinePlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a very simple (mwe) plot:

```
ListLinePlot3D[   {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}  ]
```

I want an arrow at the (1,1,1) end of this line. I need to use the `ListLinePlot3D[]` function to create this line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ReplaceAll[ Line -> Arrow] @ ListLinePlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, DisplayFunction-> ReplaceAll[Line->Arrow]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Very nice. Is there an alternative to ReplaceAll, for just one of two lines?

Comment: Also, how to make the arrow head bigger?

Comment: I see, `PlotStyle -> {{Magenta, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.05]}`

Comment: You can use `Arrowheads[0]` in `PlotStyle` for the lines to be rendered as lines. For example, `ReplaceAll[Line -> Arrow]@ ListLinePlot3D[{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, .5}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Arrowheads[.1], Arrowheads[0]}]`